# iOS: split NSString in Asian characters into substrings

Tags: ios, nsstring

I want to split string in Korean characters into substrings. For example,

`myString=@"어떻게"` into 3 substrings: `@"어", @"떻", @"게"`

What I have tried so far is:

```
[myString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@""];
```

but not successful.

Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) What isn't working? Doesn't popping off a character at a time work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `subStringWithRange` , e.g. -

```
NSString *myString = @"어떻게";

NSString *first = [myString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
NSString *second = [myString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 1)];
NSString *third = [myString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 1)];

NSLog(@"%@ , %@ , %@", first, second, third);
```

Results in `어 , 떻 , 게` at console.

Desired components are separated by nothing so, `componentSeparatedBy...` methods won't fit in an obvious manner.

Comment: look like that it is an excellent solution! BTW, do you know why did someone vote me down?

Comment: The community expects you to research thoroughly and list out your current findings as much as possible. See the link in Abizem's comment.

Comment: ok, thanks for your very clever answer and letting me know about that